# Select max of a column with multiple condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a dataset:

```
variable value zip    interval score
a        10    10017  10       8
a        10    10017  10       10
a        10    10017  11       12
a        10    10017  11       8
a        10    10018  10       8
a        10    10018  10       10
a        10    10018  11       12
a        10    10018  11       8
b        10    10017  10       11
b        10    10017  10       8
b        10    10017  11       9
b        10    10017  11       8
```

I need to find MAX of score using Oracle SQL while taking the following into consideration:

- distinct variable
- distinct zip
- distinct interval

The output of above should be:

```
variable value zip    interval score
a        10    10017  10       10
a        10    10017  11       12
a        10    10018  10       10
a        10    10018  11       12
b        10    10017  10       11
b        10    10017  11       9
```

Comment: MAX of what, value or score or...? together or independent of each other?

Comment: MAX of score. Independent of each other.

Comment: So which VALUE value do you want? (I know they are all 10 now, but that may change...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select variable,value,zip,interval, max(score)
from tab
group by variable,value,zip,interval
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select variable,value,zip,interval,max(score) 
from tab
group by variable,value,zip,interval
```

Answer (score 0):

This query should do the trick for you.

```
SELECT variable, value, zip, interval, max(score) score
FROM myTable
GROUP BY variable, value, zip, interval;
```